# cvPOSIT opencv algorithm in python cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find the Pose of a object using POSIT algorithm.Implementing the code in python. In tutorials that I found on google all examples are in c++. But how to do that in python.

In c++

```
cvPOSIT( positObject, &imagePoints[0], FOCAL_LENGTH, criteria, rotation_matrix, translation_vector );
```

What is the function call line for `cvPOSIT` in python cv2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**cvPOSIT** is obsolete, and it's functionality is replaced by **solvePnP**. There's a great tutorial [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_pose/py_pose.html), and heaps more information out there that should be easier to find now.

Comment: As per `cvPOSIT` algo we need minimum of 4 non-coplanar object coordinate points right to find Pose of object. What about this in `solvePnP`